# Visual Studio Code - output to "integrated Terminal" is corrupted / unreadable

Tags: pi-3b+, c++

the Unreadable text output from the 'integrated terminal' is shown below this line:

```
xecutinga isk:C /+/++C a++ ltndv suinfc <ndc < tarrangb ulnd.... flnd. fngnhec. hlcchhflddy
```

i am new to VScode and this output seems like an "encoding issue" but that's just a guess.
i spent 18 hours trying to resolve the output corruption & on forums looking for similar problems

the issue began immediately after the installation and continues when the debugger is run.
i reinstall on a new system with a fresh image of buster 10 and no additional programs installed but the problem persisted.

VScode was installed and run with default settings - no customization ! the problem is the same, garbled output in the 'integrated Terminal'.
in the 'problem window' at the bottom of the screen; an issue is reported that the "console": in launch.json file is not supported. i am not familiar with json type files but it is - system created at the build phase.

why does the VScode software create a statement line in launch.json that it can not support ????

removing that statement line has no effect on the corrupted text in the terminal output.
i also tried various 'encoding' options using the link on the bottom right of the screen.

both SYSTEM: Raspberry (buster -10)

VS Code Version: 1.52.1

Commit: ea3859d4ba2f3e577a159bc91e3074c5d85c0523

Date: 2020-12-16T16:30:35.090Z

Electron: 9.3.5

Chrome: 83.0.4103.122

Node.js: 12.14.1

V8: 8.3.110.13-electron.0

OS: Linux arm 5.4.79-v7+

Comment: Where is the problem with Raspberry Pi? What could be done with the RasPi to solve the problem? May this be a hardware access problem? Or is it a pure programming problem?

Comment: the problem is with VS code. Specifically when the debugger is run the default output is to a terminal window with in the VS code application - what MicroSoft calls the ‘integrated terminal’